# LaTeX-vim live preview using Ubuntu vm on windows - what's your setup?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vim

Question is pretty self explanatory. I'm using a virtual machine on my pc - either the Ubuntu app on the windows store or wsl through windows terminal, and I'm looking for a setup guide with live updating (as you type) pdf previews. I used vimtex on my mac and that worked well, but I'm having trouble configuring zathura to open its own window on windows/ubuntu. I'm fine using vimtex/zathura if anyone knows of a clear and easy to follow guide that I can use to set it up in virtual machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the issue getting `vimtex` to auto-compile as you type? A PDF viewer to auto-update as the file is recompiled? Having the PDF viewer open automatically on compilation? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a neovim plugin that does live updating as you type. You can find it [here](https://github.com/frabjous/knap/), but it won't work with regular vim. There are instructions for Zathura and other PDF viewers, but both llpp and Sioyek are better than Zathura for live updating.

Not sure about WSL but should work OK on Ubuntu. (I don't think its being a VM makes any difference.)

I had an earlier version of it years ago that did work with regular vim, but it was just proof of concept. It got picked up though by others, and the current version of it, which I think shares no code at all with my original version, is available [here](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview), I believe. I haven't tried any recent version.